# java or jdk version requirement for jsoup

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup, jdk1.4

Does Jsoup support jdk 1.4?
What is the minimum version of jdk required for jsoup?
If jsoup does not support jdk 1.4, then is there any other html parser which I can use with jdk 1.4 to edit my html.

Comment: I didn't find any info about it on jsoup homepage, so I guess you have tot test it yourself with JDK 1.4. Just run some example code from cookcbook (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) with JDK 1.4 and then you will know answer.

Answer (score 2):

jsoup requires Java 1.5. See the [jsoup download page](http://jsoup.org/download) for more information. It won't run on lower JREs.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.11.1, Jsoup requires Java 7.

Starting with version 1.14.1, Jsoup requires Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

in theory you can use the *binaries (!)* of jsoup down to java 1.2 .. however thats inadvisable. If you can, use JDK 1.5+.

most (if not all) interfaces you access are compatible to prior 1.5.